# String pyramid transition matrix

Tags: algorithm

Hi just saw a problem related NFA to DFA

Problem: given a list of leaf nodes in a pyramid ，and a map which indicates what's the possible parent node given a left and right node. Return true if the one of leaf node could turn into the root node, Otherwise, return false.

Example:

```
     root
     / \
    X   X
   /\  /\
   X  X  X
  / \/ \/ \
 A   B  C  D
```

Map:

```
        left: A |  B   |   C | D
right---------------------------------
A             B |A or C|   D | A
B             D |B or C|   A |
C                              B
D
```

Note:1. If left child is B, right child is A, the parent node could be B or C

Comment: Have you attempted to figure a solution to the problem at all?

Comment: Yes I have a brutal force solution, but some said there's a optimized way.

Comment: How do you interpret the map you gave us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def generate_status(all_status, matrix):
#  print all_status
if len(all_status) == 1:
    return all_status[0]

next_all_status = []
for i in xrange(len(all_status) - 1): 
    cur_status = set()
    for first_status in all_status: 
        for second_status in all_status[i+1]:
            cur_status |= set(list(matrix[first_status][second_status])) 
    next_all_status.append(cur_status) 

return generate_status(next_all_status, matrix)


def is_legal_status(expression, status, matrix):
    all_status = [set(s) for s in expression]

return status in generate_status(all_status, matrix)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of input data?